# Magento 2 search 3 characters with hyphen not working

Tags: magento2, php, database, search, catalogsearch

Magento 2 search **3 characters with hyphen** not working
Example -
product SKU is **4-e** - it gives lots of search results instead of related to **4-e** results(not giving related with 4-e)
there is no description,short description, and even no attributes related to **4-e**
I checked view page source no related with **4-e**

The same thing is working fine in my localhost and but it is not working with live server.

Does anyone know how to solve this?